# Model binding not working with Stream type parameter in asp.net core webapi controller action method.(Even with custom streaminputformatter)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I want to upload file to asp net core web api controller action method. I am sending content-type as "application/octet-stream". I have created custom input formatter called StreamInputFormatter. The streaminputformatter is getting called, but the action method in controller is not getting called? and Iam getting error as

"InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream."

StreamInputFormatter:

```
public class StreamInputFormatter : IInputFormatter
    {
        public bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }
            var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
            if (contentType == "application/octet-stream")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }


            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

Controller Action Method:

```
        [HttpPost("{documentType}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateJob(string documentType, [FromBody]Stream template)
        {

        }
```

Comment: where did you use StreamInputFormatter? For a middleware in Startup.cs? Can you share code?

Comment: Have you tried with a byte array? [FromBody]byte[] template

Answer (score 3):

It sounds you are getting this error because of the `DefaultObjectValidator` iterating over your unsupported `Stream` properties (see this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5642) for some information).

To skip Stream model validation, you could add

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            ...

            options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Stream)));
        });
```

to your configuration.

Comment: Whenever you have a complex type that validation will not be able to help you with the SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider is the best way to skip it

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for the full example for this, the following might help:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.InputFormatters.Add(new StreamInputFormatter());
    options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(Stream)));
});
```

StreamInputFormatter.cs

```
public class StreamInputFormatter : IInputFormatter
{
    // enter your list here...
    private readonly List<string> _allowedMimeTypes = new List<string>
        { "application/pdf", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif", "application/octet-stream" };


    public bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        var contentType = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        if (_allowedMimeTypes.Any(x => x.Contains(contentType)))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        // enable stream rewind or you won't be able to read the file in the controller   
        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        req.EnableRewind();

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        req.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Then the controller:

```
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost("customer/{customerId}/file", Name = "UploadFile")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status201Created, typeof(UploadFileResponse))]
    [Consumes("application/octet-stream", new string[] { "application/pdf", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif"})]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromBody] Stream file, [FromRoute] string customerId, [FromQuery] FileQueryParameters queryParameters)
    {
        // file processing here
    }
}
```

Comment: `return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);` does work for me without copying the stream.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It's 2022 and I wonder why this is not the default behavior built in... :(

Comment: Uploading large files is a complete mess in ASP.NET Core and in ASP.NET. It’s working against the platform at every step and you have to jump through one hoop after another. Just check the MS documentation and you can see that anything other than IFormFile is just awful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Instead I’d suggest looking into using SAS tokens and having the client upload directly to Azure Blob Storage directly instead. Just add a blob storage function trigger to then process the file (content check, virus check etc).