# How to support multiple Consumes MIME Types in ASP.NET Core controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am uploading a file as a stream with a workaround the `Stream` model binding from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346128/model-binding-not-working-with-stream-type-parameter-in-asp-net-core-webapi-cont), and I want to support consumes for multiple MIME types. I assumed this would work, but it doesn't:

```
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost("customer/{customerId}/file", Name = "UploadFile")]
    [SwaggerResponse(StatusCodes.Status201Created, typeof(UploadFileResponse))]
    [Consumes("application/octet-stream", new string[] { "application/pdf", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif"})]
    //[Consumes("application/octet-stream", "application/pdf", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/tiff", "image/tif")] // doesn't work either
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromBody] Stream file, [FromRoute] string customerId, [FromQuery] FileQueryParameters queryParameters)
    {
        // file processing here
    }
}
```

It only supports "application/octet-stream". Any of the others such as "image/jpeg" fail with a 415 Unsupported Media Type.

I am unable to add multiple `ConsumeAttributes`. The documentation for [ConsumeAttribute.ContentTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute.contenttypes?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ConsumesAttribute_ContentTypes) states:

> Gets or sets the supported request content types. Used to select an
>   action when there would otherwise be multiple matches.

I have no idea what that documentation is trying to state, but I had assumed it was a way to support extra MIME types! Is there any way around this in order to support multiple MIME types?

Update
The method signature here is fixed and can't be changed. The ConsumesAttribute is being used to generate a Swagger JSON file which clients use to generate their own multi-platform clients for this API.

Comment: I am wondering if `IFormFile` would work around that,

Comment: This is straight file upload from a http client. We don't want to use IFormFile because it is a absolute pain in the ass for non-browser clients. We just want to stream body and be done with it. MultipartFormDataContent is horrible for simple file uploads. Still the Consumes must be able to support multipel options. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: Can we convert the stream to `IFormFile`, then validating the `ContentType` property?

Comment: I'm using the ConsumesAttribute for Swagger generation (which is shared with clients, and so the interface here is fixed). Without it, the Consumes section isn't generated, and generated Swagger clients don't know which media types to support. Consumes should support multiple options, and the documentation suggests it does, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Consumes attribute is correct. I tested it with dotnet core 2.1 and it works as expected:

```
    [HttpPost("test")]
    [Consumes("text/plain", new[] { "text/html" })]
    public void Test()
    {

    }
```

Sending a post request with Content-Type "text/plain" or "text/html" works while other content types are denied with 415 unsupported media type.

BUT: It stops working if I add [FromBody] Stream file.

```
 // Does NOT work:
 [Consumes("text/plain", new[] { "text/html" })]
 public void Test([FromBody] Stream file)
```

Comment: I've tested too. As I noted at the top of my issue, I was working around the stream issue using this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346128/model-binding-not-working-with-stream-type-parameter-in-asp-net-core-webapi-cont The issue lies in there. In the CanRead method! Problem solved by adding my extra mime types into that method. No more 415's!

Comment: Is there any problem with var stream = Request.Body; ?

Comment: Changing that StreamInputFormatter solved the problem! The 415 for all the other content types was being caused by the line `if (contentType == "application/octet-stream") { return true; }`. Thank you helped me on my way proving that it should work!

Comment: Cool - and I fear I have to read about StreamInputFormatter ;-)