# Why is content-type header needed when routing to an REST WebAPI get method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, webapi

As the example code shown below, I am trying to access the get method by calling [http://localhost:51292/API/MyWebAPI/GetData/?Name=John](https://localhost:51292/API/MyWebAPI/GetData/?Name=John) then I receive an error saying **"*The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.*"**

```
public class MyData
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}
public class MyDataDTO : MyData
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyWebAPIController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetData(MyDataDTO publicInfo)
    {
        
        return Ok(publicInfo);
    }
}
```

I don't find any proper reason on why it requires the content type, maybe it has something to do with the API controller, or the routing? My routing is showen as below:

```
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "API/{controller}/{action}"
    );
    app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Comment: `I am trying to access the get method by visiting http://localhost:51292/API/MyWebAPI/GetData/?Name=John` In your web browser? In Postman? Something else?

Comment: In my web browser.

Comment: Maybe you missed adding the input formatter? [Similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346128/model-binding-not-working-with-stream-type-parameter-in-asp-net-core-webapi-cont)

Comment: Please show the request and response headers from the dev tools of your web browser.

Comment: Taking the error at face value, asp.net wants you to set a content type header so it can understand the request body - not unreasonable, and I don't know if asking "why" will solve anything- just provide the header and move on.. I'm more curious how you're managing to trigger a complaint from the server that your request has a body when it's a GET, allegedly entered into a browser address bar..

Comment: I'm also curious to know how you expect it to map the simple argument `Name=John` into a MyDataDTO. I would have expected the signature of GetData to look more like `GetData(string name)` for a url like that. If your page is sending eg json like `{"Name":"John"}` use `GetData([FromBody] xxx)` and set the content type header in the Ajax

Comment: @mjwills Accept Req Header: _Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br_

Resp Header: _Content-Length: 867
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8_

Comment: Not the accept header: that's the client telling the server what it wants back not the client telling the server what it sent (content-type)

Comment: **All** the request and response headers please. Put them in the question.

Comment: `In my web browser.` Just to be 100% clear, you typed that URL in the web browser? Or was it an AJAX / XHR request?

Comment: @CaiusJard Since it works with other Controller Actions in ASP.NET mvc when the action only accepts an object as parameter and it works by typing the action url and a property of the parameter object as the url parameter to access that Action, in this case for the WebAPI it seems to be different and I don't know why, due to what differences exactly

Comment: @mjwills URL in web browser.

Comment: Cool - please put the headers in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to add `[FromUri]` before the `MyDataDTO` object type for the Get method, such:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetData([FromUri] MyDataDTO publicInfo)
{
    
    return Ok(publicInfo);
}
```